# Prove that $F[x,y]/\langle x^2-y\rangle$ is never isomorphic to $F[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^2\rangle$, where $F$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> Prove that $F[x,y]/\langle x^2-y\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $F[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^2\rangle$, where $F$ is a field.

My solution. If they are indeed isomorphic, then they are isomorphic for any field $F$ and any value of $y$. Let us take $F=\Bbb{Q}$ and $y=-2$. Then $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^2+2\rangle$ should be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^2-4\rangle$, which is a contradiction as the first one is a field while the second one is not.

Is this a valid technique?

Comment: not really if you dont say more. in general there are algebras defined by generators and relations which are isomorphic over one field but not isomorphic over another.

Comment: I don't think you can just take $y=-2$, either.

Comment: If you want to show the statement then you have to do so for every field. Also $y$ is not a variable which value you can just set to some number from $F$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner- I can always go mod $\langle y+2\rangle$ on both sides.

Comment: I suggested an edit which perhaps clarifies the literal meaning of your question as it was originally written.

Answer (score 3):

Your technique is not valid because $F$ can be any field, for instance $\mathbb F_2$. In fact, the first is an integral domain, while the second is not (and this doesn't depend on the field).

Comment: That is my exact point. If $F$ can be any field, then it can also be $\Bbb{Q}$. And if the property does not stand true for $\Bbb{Q}$, then it is false in general

Comment: If, say, $\mathbb Q$ could help you for fields $F$ of characteristic zero, it is not helpful at all for finite fields. (Btw, the question should start like this: "Let $F$ be a field." This means that $F$ is fixed.)

Comment: I think the question means that this property is true for all fields $F$. Regardless of their characteristic. I am just proving that this property is not true for one particular field.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: The statements "$A(F)$ and $B(F)$ are isomorphic for every field $F$" and "$A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic for every field $F$" are not negations of each other. For a proof by contradiction you would need to asume that there exists a field $F$ for which both are isomorphic.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner- I'm sorry I don't quite understand what $A(F)$ and $B(F)$ are. Could you please expand on that?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan You simply misunderstood the question and I've already told you how the statement should start in order to be understood correctly.

Comment: One more thing: even if $F=\mathbb Q$ you are not allowed to give $y$ a particular value. By an isomorphism $y$ can go into something else which you can't really control.

Comment: @user26857- Suppose the question is "Let $G$ be a group. Prove or disprove that it contains the element $a$". And I show that there exists a group, say $\Bbb{Z}$, which does not contain the element $a$. Will this not be an acceptable contradiction? Disproving something by giving a specific example?

Comment: What you are really missing here is the following: **$F$ is arbitrary but fixed**.